# How to test Elastic Load Balancer on live server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns, elastic-load-balancer

I have a service running on 3 EC2 instances.
Nginx on one of the instance currently distribute the load on itself and other 2 instance's gunicorn servers.

I have setup an ELB for all three instances. How can I go about testing my ELB setup before replacing the DNS entry for our service to ELB DNS?

How can I automate this test?

Comment: How would you test now, with only Nginx setup (without ELB)?

Comment: I am a bit confused why you would like to have the same ELB in front of 3 servers out of which 1 runs different software, are the service endpoints/behavior identical?

Comment: In my previous setup, I used Nginx as a load balancer. I want to move to ELB. My current service is serving live traffic with my previous setup(Nginx one). I have created a ELB and put all three machine in target group. The end result should be all the 3 instance should be identical. And ELB would be distributing traffic. However, I want to test this before launching. What would be best way to do that?

Comment: Can you set up the ELB to point to all the servers and then hit a page or healthcheck using the ELB DNS entry which should end in .elb.amazonaws.com before repointing your existing DNS entry?